# kubernetes ingress with multiple target-rewrite

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Usually ingress rewrite target works as follows:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

This will rewrite the target of your service names as they are in the root directory. So if I have this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  rules:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: front-main
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: back-main
          servicePort: 80
```

My services are going to receive data as they are in `/`. However, I would like for my service `front-main` to send root `/` and for the server `back-main` to send `/someotherpath/`. How can I do this?

Is there something like the following line?

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "front-main: / ; back-main: /someotherpath"
```

I don't seem to find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, Ingress based on free version of Nginx do not have that feature.

But, if you can use [Nginx Plus based Ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress), you can do it by annotation.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/rewrites) from official repo:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=tea-svc rewrite=/;serviceName=coffee-svc rewrite=/beans/"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea/
        backend:
          serviceName: tea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee/
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Below are the examples of how the URI of requests to the `tea-svc` are rewritten (Note that the /tea requests are redirected to /tea/).

```
/tea/ -> /
/tea/abc -> /abc
```

Below are the examples of how the URI of requests to the `coffee-svc` are rewritten (Note that the /coffee requests are redirected to /beans/).

```
/coffee/ -> /beans/
/coffee/abc -> /beans/abc
```

Comment: Actually I used before `nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress`, however I was hoping there was a better solution.

Comment: Since this was posted, Nginx Ingress 0.22.0 was released with a new syntax for redirects (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite). I think the OP's problem can now be solved by choosing the correct capture groups. Perhaps Anton's example can also be solved using two separate ingresses with two different rewrite rules.

Comment: Has someone found already how to solve this in this new syntax? Any working example?

Answer (score 13):

Another solution is create two ingress yaml files

Each one using different annotations. It works!

Comment: It would be beneficial to see how this is done using the same host. Is there an example somewhere in the wild for this? @JuanEnciso would you have details of how this is accomplished? I'm hoping it can be done with the same "host" I wouldn't want to have my API on a separate endpoint. in this scenario.

Comment: Sorry, looked at it again, and yeah, I just got it working. The load balancer IP should stay the same, and just redirect traffic better. I should really wrap my head around, these are just passing configs to nginx in another service, really.

Comment: If you do this on digitalocean it's an extra $12/month

Answer (score 7):

The [new syntax for the rewrite annotation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/docs/examples/rewrite#examples) allows you to use capture groups to define the `rewrite-target`, which can be used *in some situations* to achieve what you're looking for.

For instance, if you want one of your services to **keep the matching url** in its rewrite but **not the other**, you could use matching groups as follow:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1$2  # Here we concatenate the two matched groups
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /front()(.*)  # Here the first matching group is always empty
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: front-main
              port:
                number: 80
        - path: /(back)(.*)  # Here the first matching group matches 'back'
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: back-main
              port:
                number: 80
```

So `/back/foo` would redirect to the `back-service` on `/back/foo`, but `/front/foo` would redirect to the `front-service` simply to `/foo`.

As far as I know, this can't be used for the more general case you asked for, like rewriting `/back/foo` to `/some-completely-different-path`.

Comment: For me the capture groups do the trick. I have my backend under `/api` and `/api` should be removed for the service. Everything else goes to my frontend service. My `rewrite-target` is `/$2` and the frontend service path is `/()(.*)` and for the backend `/api(/|$)(.*)`.

Answer (score 4):

It was a colossal pain to get this to work, but you can.

The trick is:

```
"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet" = "if ($request_uri !~* ^/(api|assets)) { rewrite ^/.*$ / break; }"
```

Assuming you're using frontend routing and all your assets are in /assets.

Here is how I set it up using terraform:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "main-ingress" {
  metadata {
    name        = "main-ingress"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class"                       = "nginx"
      "certmanager.k8s.io/issuer"                         = module.infra.cert_issuer_name
      "certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type"            = "dns01"
      "certmanager.k8s.io/acme-dns01-provider"            = "digitalocean"
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http"                  = false
      "kubernetes.io/tls-acme"                            = true
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet" = "if ($request_uri !~* ^/(api|assets)) { rewrite ^/.*$ / break; }"
    }
  }

  spec {
    tls {
      hosts       = [local.prod_hostname]
      // Needs to be different than "local.certIssuerSecretName"
      secret_name = "main-ingress-auth-tls"
    }
    rule {
      host = local.prod_hostname
      http {
        path {
          path      = "/api"
          path_type = "Prefix"
          backend {
            service {
              name = module.prod.be_service_name
              port {
                number = local.be_app_port
              }
            }
          }
        }
        path {
          path      = "/"
          path_type = "Prefix"
          backend {
            service {
              name = module.prod.fe_service_name
              port {
                number = local.fe_app_port
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm using:

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx-ingress" {
  depends_on = [ kubernetes_manifest.install-cert-manager-issuer ]
  name       = "nginx"
  version    = "4.5.2"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"
  repository = var.nginx_helm_stable_repo
  timeout    = 10 * 60
  # timeout for each k8s action - 10 minutes

  set {
    name  = "controller.publishService.enabled"
    value = "true"
  }
}
```