# Kubernetes Ingress path not finding resources

Tags: apache, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm having some issues when using a path to point to a different 
Kubernetes service.

I'm pointing to a secondary service using the path **/secondary-app** and I can see through my logs that I am correctly reaching that service.

My issue is that any included resource on the site, let's say **/css/main.css** for example, end up not found resulting in a 404.

Here's a slimmed down version of my ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: my-app
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-app.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
        path: /
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: http
      - backend:
        path: /secondary-app        
          serviceName: secondary-app
          servicePort: http
```

I've tried a few things and haven't yet been able to make it work. Do I maybe need to do some apache rewrites?

Any help would be appreciated.

### Edit - Solution

Thanks to some help from @mk_sta I was able to get my secondary service application working by using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` annotation like so:

```
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($request_uri = '/?%secondary-app') { rewrite /(.*) secondary-app/$1 break; }
```

It still needs a bit of tweaking for my specific app but that worked exactly how I needed it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` annotation in your `Ingress` configuration doesn't bring any success for multipath rewrite target paths, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514702/kubernetes-ingress-with-multiple-target-rewrite). However, you can consider to use [Nginx Plus Ingress controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress), shipped with `nginx.org/rewrites:` annotation and can be used for pointing URI paths to multiple services as described in this [example](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/rewrites).

You can also think about using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` [annotation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#configuration-snippet) for the existing `Ingress`, which can adjust rewrite rules to Nginx location, something like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite /first-app/(.*) $1 break;
      rewrite /secondary-app/(.*) /$1 break;
  name: my-app
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-app.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
        path: /first-app
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: http
      - backend:
        path: /secondary-app        
          serviceName: secondary-app
          servicePort: http
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'll read up on the examples you posted and get back to you on how it goes.

Comment: You are my saviour. I managed to get it working using the annotation "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet:". I will update my original question with my exact solution. Thanks again.