# How to rewrite target for two paths in an ingress yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an `ingress.yaml` with two paths; each to one of my microfrontends. However I'm really struggling to get the rewrite-target to work. mf1 loads correctly, but mf2 doesn't. I've done some research and know I need to use [Captured Groups](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/docs/examples/rewrite#examples), but can't seem to properly implement this. How do I do that?

This is what my ingress looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: mf1
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /mf2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: mf2
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kubernetes ingress with multiple target-rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514702/kubernetes-ingress-with-multiple-target-rewrite)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression capture group in your `path` expression, and then reference the capture group in your `.../rewrite-target` annotation.

That might look like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /()(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend1
                port:
                  name: http
          - path: /mf2(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend2
                port:
                  name: http
```

We need to ensure that for both rules, capture group `$2` contains the desired path. For the first rule (`path: /`), we have an empty group `$1` (because it's not necessary here), with the entire path captured in `$2`.

For the second rule, we match either `/mf2` followed by either a `/path...` or as the end of the url (this ensures we don't erroneously match `/mf2something`). Group `$1` will contain the `/` (or nothing), and the path goes into `$2`.

In both cases, the rewritten path (`/$2`) will have what we want.